# How to insert a string to the beginning of a stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

For example only and not the actual code:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << " world!";

string hello("Hello");

// insert hello to beginning of ss ??
```

Thanks for all the responses, I also found this code, which works:

```
ostringstream& insert( ostringstream& oss, const string& s )
{
  streamsize pos = oss.tellp();
  oss.str( s + oss.str() );
  oss.seekp( pos + s.length() );
  return oss;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You cannot do it without making at least one copy. One way:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << " world!";

const std::string &temp = ss.str();
ss.seekp(0);
ss << "Hello";
ss << temp;
```

This relies on the "most important `const`" to extend the lifetime of the temporary and avoid making an extra copy.

Or, simpler and possibly faster:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << " world!";

std::stringstream temp;
temp << "Hello";
temp << ss.rdbuf();
ss = std::move(temp); // or ss.swap(temp);
```

This borrows the `rdbuf` approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8231813), since the interesting problem here is how to minimize copies.

Comment: So it does, my bad.

Comment: @NicHartley: No problem, but would you mind removing your downvote? :)

Comment: Votes are locked in after 15 minutes, so unfortunately I can't. The `seekp` thing solved my problem; I'd upvote this if I could.

Comment: @NicHartley: Ah. No worries. I believe the `seekp` approach copies more data around, even with C++11 move semantics. Come to think of it, the simplest and fastest approach is probably just to create a new `stringstream` and `swap` (or `std::move`) the guts. I went ahead and edited my answer, which also should allow you to change your vote.

Answer (score 3):

the only way i can see is to create the string from stream and prefix your other string

```
string result = hello + ss.str();
```

its called a stream for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming **ss1** contains **"hello"**

```
ss1 << ss.rdbuf();
```

or

```
ss1 << "hello" << ss;
```

Refer this URL for more info:-

**[stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/)**