# concatenate stringstream in c++

Tags: c++, concatenation, stringstream

How can I concatenate two stringstreams?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include "types.h"    

int main () {
    char dest[1020] = "you";
    char source[7] = "baby";
    stringstream a,b;
    a << source;
    b << dest;
    a << b; /*HERE NEED CONCATENATE*/
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << a.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the following in both tries:

```
0xbf8cfd20
baby0xbf8cfddc
```

The desired output is `babyyou`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Should be:

```
b << dest;
a << b.str();
```

[`stringstream::str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) returns the underlying string in the `stringstream`.

Comment: Of course as mentioned you don't need 2 `stringstream`s in this case, however I assumed that the given example is a trivial version of some more complex use case.

Comment: This will create a copy of b's string data; I think the questioner may be looking for a way to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 9):

Or

```
a << b.rdbuf();
```

provided that get pointer is on the beginning of the stream to avoid allocating yet another `std::string` for content.

Answer (score 6):

More generically across iostreams:

```
std::istream is1, is2; // eg. (i)stringstream
std::ostream os;       // eg. (o)stringstream

os << is1.rdbuf();
os << is2.rdbuf();
os << std::flush;
```

This works for filestreams, std::cin etc. as well as for stringstream

Answer (score 5):

You don't need two instance of `std::stringstream`. One is enough for the purpose.

```
std::stringstream a;
a << source << dest;

std::string s = a.str(); //get the underlying string
```

Answer (score 1):

The question was "how to concatenate STREAMS", the answers explained how to concatenate the contents of the streams. Here is a class which can be used to concatenate two istreams into one istream (file ConcatStreams.h):

```
class ConcatStreams
: public std::streambuf {
std::streambuf* sbuf1_;
std::streambuf* sbuf2_;
char*           buffer_;
int useBuf;
int bufSize;
public:
ConcatStreams(std::streambuf* sbuf1, std::streambuf* sbuf2)
    : bufSize(1024), sbuf1_(sbuf1), sbuf2_(sbuf2), buffer_(new char[bufSize]), useBuf(1) {
}
ConcatStreams(const ConcatStreams& orig);
virtual ~ConcatStreams() { delete[] this->buffer_; }
int underflow() {
    if (this->gptr() == this->egptr()) {
        // get data into buffer_, obtaining its input from
        // this->sbuf_; if necessary resize buffer
        // if no more characters are available, size == 0.
        std::streamsize size=0;
        if(useBuf==1) {
            size = this->sbuf1_->sgetn(this->buffer_, bufSize);
            if(!size) { useBuf++;}
        } 
        if(useBuf==2) {
            size = this->sbuf2_->sgetn(this->buffer_, bufSize);
            if(!size) { useBuf++;}
        }
        this->setg(this->buffer_, this->buffer_, this->buffer_ + size);
    }
    return this->gptr() == this->egptr()
         ? std::char_traits<char>::eof()
         : std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(*this->gptr());
 }
};
```

To use it:

```
#include "ConcatStreams.h"
istringstream msgIn1("this is a stream.");
istringstream msgIn2("this is another stream.");
ConcatStreams cs(msgIn1.rdbuf(), msgIn2.rdbuf());
istream msgIn(&cs);
cout << "'" << msgIn.rdbuf() << "'" << endl;
```

Basically the class uses the streambuf's from the streams passed to it to create a new streambuf which first reads the first streambuf and then reads the second streambuf when finished with the first one.

Comment: This class is bugged (the initialization of `bufSize` comes _after_ the use in constructing `buffer_`) and is generally unnecessarily low-level. Here's a c++17 version https://stackoverflow.com/a/49441066/85371

Answer (score 0):

Just replace  `a << b` with `a << b.str()`