# Composite std::istream in C++

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iostream

I have a list of `std::istream` objects that I need to appear as a single `std::istream` object. So if I have three `istream`s, A, B and C, I want to be able to create an `istream`, D which will first return the bytes from A then the bytes from B, then C before `EOF` is reached.  The composite stream will always be read sequentially and closed after all bytes are read.

Is there a simple way to do this using stl/boost or do I just need to write my own composite istream?

Comment: Check out Boost.Iostreams.

Comment: Until you need to inherit from std::ios, I'd say the most straightforward way is building a composite istream, having a queue of other streams.

Comment: Are you saying you have a *`std::list`* of istreams? Meaning `std::list<std::istream>`?

Comment: Not actually in a std::list but an ordered set of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The off-topic answer to another question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17103292/1424877) might help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class ConcatStreams : public std::streambuf
{
    int useBuf;
    std::streambuf *sbuf_[2];
    char buffer_[1024];

  public:
    ConcatStreams(std::istream& sbuf1, std::istream& sbuf2) :
        useBuf(0), sbuf_{sbuf1.rdbuf(), sbuf2.rdbuf()}
    { }

    int underflow()
    {
        if (this->gptr() == this->egptr()) {
            std::streamsize size = 0;
            while (useBuf < 2) {
                size = this->sbuf_[useBuf]->sgetn(this->buffer_, sizeof this->buffer_);
                if (!size) {
                    useBuf++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } 
            this->setg(this->buffer_, this->buffer_, this->buffer_ + size);
        }
        return this->gptr() == this->egptr()
             ? std::char_traits<char>::eof()
             : std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(*this->gptr());
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::istringstream is("hello world!\n");

    ConcatStreams cs_(is, std::cin); // prepend "hello world" to the input
    std::istream cs(&cs_);

    std::string s;
    while (cs >> s)
      std::cout << "'" << s << "'" << std::endl;
}
```

Notice that you can't use this particular trick to concatenate `std::cin` with itself, or even `is` with itself; but it should work fine to concatenate any two *different* input streams. You can even concatenate multiple `ConcatStreams` instances!