# Is it possible to use two files in one fstream, where the end of one file is replaced by the second file?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, eof, ofstream

I am wanting to concatenate two files and then pass the combined file to a library that takes in a single istream and parses it. My current solution is to write a temp file, write the contents of the two original files to that, and then open this temp file for reading, then delete the temp file.

Here is my current solution:

```
ifstream f_template("file_1.txt");
if (f_template.fail()) {
    return ERR;
}
ifstream f_port("file_2.txt");
if (f_port.fail()) {
    return ERR;
}
ofstream concat("tmp.txt");
if (concat.fail()) {
    return ERR;
}

concat << f_template.rdbuf() << f_port.rdbuf();
f_template.close();
f_port.close();
concat.close();

ifstream res("tmp.txt");
if (res.fail()) {
    return ERR;
}

// now pass res to the parser.
```

I've been trying to brainstorm a more elegant solution, but I can't seem to find a way. My original idea was to have some sort of handler for when the first file hits EOF in order to redirect it to reading the second file instead of sending the EOF to the parser, but I'm not sure how I would achieve this. Does anyone have any advice?

EDIT: The result was able to be achieved by writing the two files to a stringstream and passing the library that. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: You could derive from `fstream` and provide your own class that has the functionality that you want, but that can be a pretty big task.

Comment: Does the library literally take `fstream`? Not `istream`? If it's `istream`, you'll be able to pass an `std::stringstream` to it, so the result of the concatenation can stay in memory.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506444/composite-stdistream-in-c ?

Comment: classic example of [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). First explain why you need this, then maybe someone will be able propose alternative solution where explicit concatenation of streams is not needed. For example maybe it would be easier to design better API for code which needs those streams.

Comment: as a side note: normally you write `if (!res)` or `if (!res.is_open())` and not `if (res.fail())`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, this did it. I misread the function originally -- it did take an istream, not an fstream, so using a stringstream was a perfect solution for me. Thank you!!